# share menu opens at twice rather just when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have added a share menu to my game, when the game is over the game over pop up appears with a share menu. when i press anywhere on the screen the share menu pops up and the game goes back to the beginning prompting the player to Tap to play again. Then when the player taps on the screen the share menu pops up again which makes the game unplayable after the first play through. I think i need to set the share menu to pop up only when SKSpriteNode for the share button is pressed, if the player taps anywhere else on the screen the game should just reset. Would be grateful if you could take a look at code and see where i am going wrong.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var shareButton = SKSpriteNode()

var santa = SKSpriteNode()

var bg = SKSpriteNode()

var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()

var tapToPlayLabel = SKLabelNode()

var score = 0

var gameOverScreen = SKSpriteNode()

var timer = Timer()

enum ColliderType: UInt32 {

    case santa = 1
    case Object = 2
    case Gap = 4

}

enum ButtonName: String {

    case play
    case share

}

var gameOver = false

func makeBlocks() {

    let moveBlocks = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -2 * self.frame.width, dy: 0), duration: TimeInterval(self.frame.width / 100))

    let gapHeight = santa.size.height * 4

    let movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.height / 2)

    let blockOffset = CGFloat(movementAmount) - self.frame.height / 4

    let blockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "block1.png")

    let block1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockTexture)

    block1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX + self.frame.width, y: self.frame.midY + blockTexture.size().height / 2 + gapHeight / 2 + blockOffset)

    block1.run(moveBlocks)

    block1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: blockTexture.size())
    block1.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    block1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    block1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    block1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue

    block1.zPosition = -2

    self.addChild(block1)

    let block2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "block2.png")

    let block2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: block2Texture)

    block2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX + self.frame.width, y: self.frame.midY - block2Texture.size().height / 2 - gapHeight / 2 + blockOffset)

    block2.run(moveBlocks)

    block2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: blockTexture.size())
    block2.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    block2.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    block2.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    block2.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue

    block2.zPosition = -2

    self.addChild(block2)

    let gap = SKNode()

    gap.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX + self.frame.width, y: self.frame.midY + blockOffset)

    gap.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: blockTexture.size().width, height: gapHeight))

    gap.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    gap.run(moveBlocks)

    gap.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.santa.rawValue
    gap.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Gap.rawValue
    gap.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Gap.rawValue

    self.addChild(gap)

}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if gameOver == false {

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Gap.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Gap.rawValue {

        score += 1

        scoreLabel.text = String(score)


    } else {

    self.speed = 0

    gameOver = true

    timer.invalidate()

    let gameOverScreenTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "GameOverPopup.jpg")

    var j: CGFloat = 0

    gameOverScreen = SKSpriteNode(texture: gameOverScreenTexture, size: CGSize(width: 600, height: 600))

    gameOverScreen.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

    gameOverScreen.size.height = self.frame.height / 3


    gameOverScreen.zPosition = -1

    self.addChild(gameOverScreen)


     //share button

    let shareButtonTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shareButton.png")

    var k: CGFloat = 0

    shareButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: shareButtonTexture, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 100))

    shareButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

    shareButton.size.height = self.frame.height / 10

    shareButton.name = "shareButton"

    shareButton.zPosition = 0

    self.addChild(shareButton)




        }
    }

}

func openShareMenu(value: String, image: UIImage?) {
    guard let view = view else { return }

    // Activity items
    var activityItems = [AnyObject]()

    // Text
    let text = "Can you beat my score "
    activityItems.append(text as AnyObject)

    // Add image if valid
    if let image = image {
        activityItems.append(image)
    }

    // Activity controller
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)


    // Excluded activity types
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityType.airDrop,
        UIActivityType.print,
        UIActivityType.assignToContact,
        UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
    ]

    // Present
    view.window?.rootViewController?.present(activityController, animated: true)
}



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    addChild(shareButton)

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    setupGame()

}

func setupGame() {

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.makeBlocks), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    let bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg.png")

    let moveBGAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -bgTexture.size().width, dy: 0), duration: 7)
    let shiftBGAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: bgTexture.size().width, dy: 0), duration: 0)
    let moveBGForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBGAnimation, shiftBGAnimation]))

    var i: CGFloat = 0

    while i < 3 {

        bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)

        bg.position = CGPoint(x: bgTexture.size().width * i, y: self.frame.midY)

        bg.size.height = self.frame.height

        bg.run(moveBGForever)

        bg.zPosition = -3

        self.addChild(bg)

        i += 1

    }


    let santaTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "santa1.png")
    let santaTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "santa2.png")

    let animation = SKAction.animate(with: [santaTexture, santaTexture2], timePerFrame: 0.1)
    let makeSantaMove = SKAction.repeatForever(animation)

    santa = SKSpriteNode(texture: santaTexture)

    santa.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

    santa.run(makeSantaMove)

    santa.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: santaTexture.size().height / 2)

    santa.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    santa.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    santa.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.santa.rawValue
    santa.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.santa.rawValue

    self.addChild(santa)

    let ground = SKNode()

    ground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: -self.frame.height / 2)

    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: 1))

    ground.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    ground.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    ground.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    ground.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue


    self.addChild(ground)

    scoreLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"

    scoreLabel.fontSize = 60

    scoreLabel.text = "0"

    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.height / 2 - 220)

    self.addChild(scoreLabel)

    tapToPlayLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"

    tapToPlayLabel.fontSize = 70

    tapToPlayLabel.text = "Tap to Play!"

    tapToPlayLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.height / 2 - 500)

    self.addChild(tapToPlayLabel)


}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if gameOver == false {

     tapToPlayLabel.isHidden = true

     santa.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true

     santa.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

     santa.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 320))

    } else {

        tapToPlayLabel.isHidden = false

        gameOver = false

        score = 0

        self.speed = 1

        self.removeAllChildren()

        setupGame()

    }


    if let name = shareButton.name {

        if name == "shareButton" {

            openShareMenu(value: "\(self.score)", image: nil)


        }

    }

 }

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
  }

}
```

Comment: I only see one place in the code where you explicitly call "openShareMenu". Set a breakpoint on the first line of openShareMenu function and on the left hand side you can see a trace of who's calling the openShareMenu function. Note the answer to what you need, but a trouble shooting tip. Many times I've accidentally wired something from a .xib or .storyboard file not realizing I was calling calling code I did not expect to call.

Comment: How would you suggest i fix this problem, nothing has been wired from the .xib or .storyboard, i think the issue is where the code is placed or i need to add some more code to only open the share button when it is pressed and never any other time

Comment: Not sure if I have enough context with the code you provided. I do see that you make the activityController available through the rootViewController and I don’t see the code that tells the controller what to do when it’s up/dismissed. 
You might try bringing it up through the NavigationController if your view is embedded in a nav controller navigationController?.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true) {
    // Code called when controller is up.
}
present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem, the game now restarts as it should. My only problem is I need to set bounds for the share button so any touches on the button should open the share menu. At the moment a touch anywhere on the screen will open the menu. Any ideas?

Comment: Glad to hear you got that fixed. You should google "programmatically create uiview or uibutton" which will cover that topic which should help with what you need.

Comment: @ xdeleon We dont want to use UIKit in SpriteKit. @ uz7 Check my answer to see where you went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the touches method wrong. You are not using the name of the touched node to see if it is the share button. You merely assign a property (if let name = ...) and see if its the share button. You need to compare with the name of the actual node that is touched. You are also running your gameOver code anytime touchesBegan fires, you need to differentiate.

Try this

```
   override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

         for touch in touches {
             let location = touch.location(in: self) // get location of touch
             let nodeTouched = atPoint(location) // get touched node

             // Pressed button
             if let nodeName = nodeTouched.name {
                  switch nodeName {
                  case ButtonName.share.rawValue:
                     openShareMenu(value: "\(self.score)", image: nil)
                     return // return early if share button is pressed so your gameOver code below etc doesnt fire.

                  default: 
                      break
                }
           }

           // Did not press button, usual code
            if gameOver == false {..... }
      }
 }
```

Hope this helps